# How do I change the number of steps in a staircase using 3DS Max?

Tags: 3ds-max

[image]

It stays locked always at 12, I don't know how to change it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Click the Pin Icon of one of the other 3 options. This will lock the parameter and unlock the Riser Count.

[image: image showing options]